# Static functions are not found in the browser

Tags: javascript, typescript, browserify

I am trying to get static methods to execute in the browser, but currently I can not get the browser to see them...

**MyClass.ts**

```
export class MyClass {

    public static myFunc(){
        // Do stuff here
    }

}
```

**main.ts**

```
import { MyClass } from './MyClass.ts';
```

Now when I build this:

```
gulp.task('ts-compile', () => {

    return browserify()
        .add('./src/main.ts')
        .plugin(tsify)
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function(error) {
            console.error(error);
        })
        .pipe(source('blueberry.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(minify({
            ext: {
                min: '.min.js'
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))

});
```

It builds out, but the output file does not have `MyClass` in it anymore.

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
"use strict";

},{}]},{},[1]);
```

When I try to access it in the browser like so:

```
MyClass.myFunc()
```

I the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MyClass is not defined

In my main.ts file, if I add it to the window like this:

```
import { MyClass } from './MyClass.ts';
window['MyClass'] = new MyClass();
```

I then get this output:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
"use strict";
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
    }
    MyClass.myFunc = function () {
        console.log('Found Me!');
    };
    return MyClass;
}());
exports.MyClass = MyClass;

},{}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
"use strict";
var MyClass_ts_1 = require('./MyClass.ts');
window['MyClass'] = new MyClass_ts_1.MyClass();

},{"./MyClass.ts":1}]},{},[2]);
```

With this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: MyClass.myFunc is not a function

I can not figure out how to make the static functions accessible in the browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window['MyClass']` --- this variable holds a reference to an instance of `MyClass` not to a class itself. And an instance, obviously, does not have a `myFunc` method, since it is static.

If you want the global `MyClass` variable to hold a reference to the class, change your code to:

```
window['MyClass'] = MyClass;
```

Comment: HAHA, I tried that too, but had parenthesis, and it was giving me an error. Without the parenthesis it works! Thanks for the quick reply! What is the difference?

Comment: `new MyClass()` is a constructor call, `MyClass()` is a function call, `MyClass` is a reference to a class.